# Any trusted phone Android app that simply helps to split all photos by swiping into Top100, Top1000, Default and Trash folders or so?

Tags: android, video, photography, directories, android-app

I'm looking for the any trusted phone Android app that simply helps to split all photos by swiping into Top100, Top1000, Default and Trash folders or so. Is there any?

There are many photos on my phone, some of them needs to be deleted, some of them are the best. To sort the phone photos, of course, I can copy the photos to my computer, then create 4 folders or so and consequently review and copy each photo into one or another folder depending on my preferences.

I'm looking for a faster, but trusted way. I think phone works faster when reviewing photos than my computer.

Ideally, I can pause my work with photos and continue any time later so that work with photos continues (as far as I need many hours on that work) from time to time until finished.

Do we have any useful free software for that purpose? Thank you.

If not, then the idea is for the software: Top10 folder - swipe to top, Top1000 folder - swipe to bottom, Default folder - swipe to right, Trash - swipe to left. And show the next one.

This is about photos and videos - for all types of medias.

P.S. Of course, nothing bad happens, if I move 11th photo into Top10 folder or 1253th video into Top1000 folder. Thank you.